# Cloth simulation broke after slight geometry change

Tags: mesh, cloth-simulation

Whats up
I made this first simulation of a pair of shorts falling and then getting blown away with some wind and it looks pretty good.

[image]

Now i tried to add the waist folds by selecting the upper row of faces, checker deselect, slightly inset them and added some sub surf to smooth it out, but now the cloth reacts unexpectedly contracting on itself when the simulation begins.

[image: Text]

It has to do with the self collision because if i turn it off it wont bend.

Any ideas how it can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tweak the *Self Collisions > Friction* (here set to 15) it seems to work fine.

Edit: So, according to you, the best is to increase the *Distance* value.

[image]

Comment: That is not working fine at all hahaha the idea was that it stopped bending on itself and simply fall without distortion.
However, i tried touching the self collision settings and found that the problem was not Friction, but rather the Distance. I put it down from 0.015 to 0.07 and it seems to do the trick. My guess is that the inset faces on the upper row were bumping against each other thus making it behave weirdly in that zone, so having a shorter distance for self collisions stops them from doing that.

Thanks a lot for stepping in tho, this had me going nuts :)

Comment: oh ok great then  ;)